# How to read and store XML generated by CGI script from a URL address

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, cgi, cross-domain

I have a problem about reading XML file which generated by CGI

Say I have a url address like this:

```
http://test.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/generateXML.cgi?listxml=1&oid=10037&bidderid=6217&aid=25731&tote=
```

If I open it in the browser, it will return a xml file and display it in the browser.

Now what I need to do is using javascript and jQuery to retrive this XML file generated by this address.

I have try the code like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert("HELLO!");

    var self = this;
    var target;

     $.get("http://test.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/generateXML.cgi?listxml=1&oid=10037&bidderid=6217&aid=25731&tote=", function(d){  
        $(d).find("sale").each(function(){
         target = ($(this).find("target").text());
         alert(target);
        });
    });

});
```

But this doesn't work. The XML can't be get.

Also I need to mention that the code is now on my local computer, and the URL address, the cgi file is on another server. So I guess there may be some cross domain restriction?

I just have no idea where to start with. Can anyone help me? Thank you!!

Comment: What error does it give? Are you running this code in the same domain? Does your xml file have text/xml content-type?

Comment: Hi @timidboy, thank you for your reply. The error given by chrome is like : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/generateXML.cgi?listxml=1&oid=10037&bidderid=6217&aid=25731&tote=. Origin http://arthur.local is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: They are ont in the same domain. So you mean this is a cross-domain problem? I just wonder if the way I try to still use .get to access and store the XML file which from a dynamic CGI script are still correct.

Comment: Yes, try Musa's answer and that should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the better way is using jQuery.parseXML()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 0):

> So I guess there may be some cross domain restriction?

Yes. If you have control over the other server you'll have to set some [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers to the cgi response, like

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost
```

Comment: Thank you @Musa, So is the way I try to use .get to access and store the XML file correct?